# How to insert values into a table from a list

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

I have a list and a table like below and what I need to do is to go through values in the item name column in the table and find the item name that is available in a list but missing from the table if there is any.
then I need to insert that missing item_name into the table with null value for the item value column and the same timestamp as others for the timestamp column.

list_of_tags = ["item_1",
"item_2",
"item_3",
"item_4",
"item_5",
"item_1_a",
"item_1_b",
"item_1_c",
"item_1_d",
"item_1_e"
]

```
|item_name | item_value | timestamp |
|:-------  |:------:| ----------------------------:|
| item_1   | 23.2   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_2   | 45.2   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_3   | 34.3   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_4   | 56.3   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_1_a | 23.2   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_2_b | 45.2   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_3_c | 34.3   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_4_d | 56.3   | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
```

the outcome I want is

```
|item_name | item_value  | timestamp                    |
|:------   |:------------:| ----------------------------:|
| item_1   | 23.2         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_2   | 45.2         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_3   | 34.3         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_4   | 56.3         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_4   | 56.3         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_5   | null         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_1_a | 23.2         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_2_b | 45.2         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_3_c | 34.3         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_4_d | 56.3         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
| item_5_e | null         | 2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000 |
```

How can I do this using Pyspark?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the missing item names to get the original DataFrame using the unionByName function.
Here is How you can do it

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, to_timestamp, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, DoubleType, TimestampType, StructType, StructField
```

From the libraries above you have to import the  required datatypes and functions.

**Create DataFrame from the given table**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() 

data = [
    ("item_1", 23.2, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_2", 45.2, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_3", 34.3, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_4", 56.3, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_5", None, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),  
    ("item_1_a", 23.2, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_2_b", 45.2, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_3_c", 34.3, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_4_d", 56.3, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000"),
    ("item_5_e", None, "2023-05-08T20:00:00.000+0000")  
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["item_name", "item_value", "timestamp"])
```

**Now Convert timestamp column to TimestampType()**

```
df = df.withColumn("timestamp", to_timestamp(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

**Create DataFrame from the list of tags**

```
list_of_tags = [
    "item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4", "item_5",
    "item_1_a", "item_2_b", "item_3_c", "item_4_d", "item_5_e"
]

schema = StructType([
    StructField("item_name", StringType(), nullable=False),
    StructField("item_value", DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), nullable=False)
])


existing_items = df.select("item_name").distinct().collect()
existing_timestamp = df.select("timestamp").first()[0]

missing_items = [item for item in list_of_tags if item not in [row.item_name for row in existing_items]]

missing_items_df = spark.createDataFrame([(item, None, existing_timestamp) for item in missing_items], schema)
```

**Add missing item names to the original DataFrame and replace null values**

```
updated_df = df.unionByName(missing_items_df)
updated_df = updated_df.fillna({"item_value": "null"})
```

**Return the updated DataFrame**

```
updated_df.display(truncate=False)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]